# Ext JS - on sencha production build, sencha cmd is removing extra attribute in index.html file

Tags: extjs, content-security-policy, sencha-cmd, nonce

For Content security policy, I have added `nonce` to microloader script tag to bypass the inline script generated when index.html is re-written after production build as below

```
script id="microloader" nonce="random" data-app="random-app" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"
```

but I have observed the `nonce="random"` getting strip after the sencha build(production).
Because of this, csp is through an error for the inline JS that is imbedded in between script tag.

How can I stop sencha removing the added `nonce`?

Answer (score 0):

Which file are you updating?build\production\SenchaApp.. Don't update this because it always rewrites by the sencha cmd. Better to update root level index.html then build again

Comment: I have updated the nonce in the root level original file. But after 'sencha app build production', in this 'build\production\SenchaApp' path, as the sencha is rewriting the file, its removing the nonce in the above mentioned place.
Is there any configuration in app.json to retain the nonce in that place?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making use of the --after-build target in the build.xml ant script. From there you could manually edit/update the build's index.html to insert the nonce attribute automatically into the script tag.